# Evaluate dict as edge weight in networkx

Tags: python, networkx

In a networkx multigraph, I stored a dictionary of different values (in the following example `a` and `b`). How do I evaluate the weight (e.g. `lambda` or key) for shortest path algorithms (e.g., for Dijkstra)? For the evaluation, it is either `a` or `b`.

```
import networkx as nx
G = nx.MultiGraph()

G.add_edge('a', 'b', weight_dict={'a' : 1, 'b': 2})
G.add_edge('a', 'b', weight_dict={'a' : 10, 'b': 9})
G.add_edge('b', 'c', weight_dict={'a' : 1, 'b': 1})
G.add_edge('a', 'c', weight_dict={'a' : 30, 'b': 30})

nx.multi_source_dijkstra(G, {'a'}, weight=lambda u, v, d: G[u][v][d]['a']) # obviously does not work
```

Answer (score 0):

Since it's a multigraph, as preprocessing, one could retrieve the set of edges with minimal weight (for a given attribute name). Then, according to the `networkx` documentation,

> weight (string or function) – If this is a function, the weight of an edge is the value returned by the function. The function must accept exactly three positional arguments: the two endpoints of an edge and the dictionary of edge attributes for that edge. The function must return a number.

```py
import networkx as nx
import pandas as pd

#Function to get minimal edges per attribute name
def get_edge_attributes(G, name):    
    edges = G.edges(data=True)
    rows = [(e[0],e[1],e[-1]['weight_dict'][name]) for e in edges]
    df = pd.DataFrame(rows)
    df = df.iloc[df.groupby([0,1])[2].idxmin()]
    return df

G = nx.MultiGraph()

G.add_edge('a', 'b', weight_dict={'a' : 1, 'b': 2})
G.add_edge('a', 'b', weight_dict={'a' : 10, 'b': 9})
G.add_edge('b', 'c', weight_dict={'a' : 1, 'b': 1})
G.add_edge('a', 'c', weight_dict={'a' : 30, 'b': 30})


attribute_name = 'a'

#Retrieve minimal weigths
subweight = get_edge_attributes(G,attribute_name)

#Function to retrieve weigths. It takes into account that the graph is undirected.
def return_weight(u,v,d):
    x = subweight[((subweight[0]==u)&(subweight[1]==v))|
                  ((subweight[1]==u)&(subweight[0]==v))][2].values[0]
    return x

# Run
nx.multi_source_dijkstra(G, {'a'}, weight=return_weight)
```

Running with `attribute_name = 'a'` yields

```py
({'a': 0, 'b': 1, 'c': 2}, {'a': ['a'], 'b': ['a', 'b'], 'c': ['a', 'b', 'c']})
```

whereas `attribute_name = 'b'` yields

```py
({'a': 0, 'b': 2, 'c': 3}, {'a': ['a'], 'b': ['a', 'b'], 'c': ['a', 'b', 'c']})
```